# Flink stream processing count unique issues per repo

Tags: git, scala, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm working with Flink in Scala, and I'm trying to get the count of unique issues per repo. I have a datastream with tuples like this: (repo_name, issue_id, event_time). 
How can I obtain the count of unique issue_id's for each repo_name? I think I have to use `mapWithState`, but I am not sure how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting an endless stream that updates each time there's a new unique issue, or is this windowed (e.g. daily or weekly counts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you want to process the events in a tumbling time window of 7 days.

```
// eventStream: stream of case classes of type GithubEvent 
eventStream
   // only look at IssuesEvent
  .filter(e => e.`type` == "IssuesEvent")
   // key by the name of the repository
  .keyBy("repo.name")
   // tumbling time window of a week
  .timeWindow(Time.days(7))
   // apply window function
  .apply { (key, _, vals, out: Collector[(String)]) =>
    var count = 0;
    for (_ <- vals) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
    out.collect(s"Repo name: $key Unique issues: $count")
  }
```

To count the number of unique issues per repository, we need to look at [IssuesEvents](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuesevent). We key by the name of the repository. Then, we apply a window function to return a String indicating the unique number of issues.

References:

- [Introducing Stream Windows in Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html)
- [Flink Windows](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/stream/operators/windows.html)